# How to connect to SQL Server 2014 installed on one PC from a 2nd PC without Windows server and domain involved?

Tags: sql-server

I have a Toshiba laptop with Windows 7 on which I have installed SQL Server 2014 for my database and use Microsoft Access 2016 to manage the data in a user-friendly way.

Everything worked perfectly fine till I tried to connect to the database from another PC on the same network, also with Windows 7.

I am able to connect to the database from the second PC using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and SQL Server Native Client 11.0, logging in as `sa` using SQL Server authentication.

However, when I open the Microsoft Access database file from the second PC, a window pops up, saying that:

[See this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skt1u.jpg)

And when I press OK a second window pops:

[See this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDqT2.jpg)

I have configured the database to use a specific TCP/IP = 1433

Also made new inbound rules in windows firewall for all SQL Server services.
Please note that there is no domain involved here. I don't have a Windows server and the SQL Server is installed on PC #1.

If you require more information, please tell me, I'll be happy to provide

Hope someone will be able to help!

Comment: your error shows that your access database is trying to use windows authentication.

Comment: Uncheck Use Trusted Connection and then enter SQL Server-provided credentials.

Comment: uncheck the "use trusted connection" and enter a valid login and password

Comment: Yes, I can see that even know I have logged in as "sa" and password using SQL Server Authentication . It does not allow me to login with Windows Authentication from the second PC.  Windows Authentication and Sql Server Authentication is enabled by the way.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I I have tried to uncheck the "use trusted connection" and logged in as "sa" and password. It does do the trick but right after I click on a button or anywhere else in MS Access it pops up again.

Comment: Is it required to have a windows server and a domain running to be able to  access the database from another pc?

Comment: So, no one can answer this simple question>? :( This seems to be a useless forum then :(

Answer (score 0):

try to use LINKSERVER

Using SQL Server Management Studio

To create a linked server to another instance of SQL Server Using SQL Server Management Studio
In SQL Server Management Studio, open Object Explorer, expand Server Objects, right-click Linked Servers, and then click New Linked Server.
On the General page, in the Linked server box, type the name of the instance of SQL Server that you area linking to.

SQL Server
Identify the linked server as an instance of Microsoft SQL Server. If you use this method of defining a SQL Server linked server, the name specified in Linked server must be the network name of the server. Also, any tables retrieved from the server are from the default database defined for the login on the linked server.

Other data source
Specify an OLE DB server type other than SQL Server. Clicking this option activates the options below it.

Provider
Select an OLE DB data source from the list box. The OLE DB provider is registered with the given PROGID in the registry.

Product name
Type the product name of the OLE DB data source to add as a linked server.

Data source
Type the name of the data source as interpreted by the OLE DB provider. If you are connecting to an instance of SQL Server, provide the instance name.

Provider string
Type the unique programmatic identifier (PROGID) of the OLE DB provider that corresponds to the data source. For examples of valid provider strings, see sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL).

Location
Type the location of the database as interpreted by the OLE DB provider.

Catalog
Type the name of the catalog to use when making a connection to the OLE DB provider.

[image]

http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2014/tutorial/linked_servers.cfm